Onna vs Onna no hito vs Onna no kata
I know there's a kanji for Onna so I am confused on why you should add no hito or no kata after it and when? Is it just to state that there's just one person?

It's 女の人, not 女の一.  Nothing about 女の人 implies number.  It could be singular or plural.  I'll leave it to others to explain why this is the expression more typically used than just 女.  Incidentally, it's the same with 男の人.  Analogously, there's also 女の子 and 男の子, though these two refer to children (girls and boys).
